# How do you get new sites into your Quantcast network?

Tags: analytics

Over a month ago, we added some of the new Stack Exchange sites to the "Stack Overflow Network" on Quantcast, but to date, they haven't showed up:

http://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc#subdomain

Is this because of traffic numbers, or because we did something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Just realized that e.g. Area 51 seems quantified since June already, plus Quantcast is listing subdomains within networks with data less than 30 days anyway, so this really shouldn't be an issue. Digging around a bit more led me to the following *best guess*:

If you introspect their showcase site [gawker.com](http://www.quantcast.com/gawker.com) you'll find that its parent [Gawker Media Network](http://www.quantcast.com/p-d4P3FpSypJrlA) is comprised of [9 sites](http://www.quantcast.com/p-d4P3FpSypJrlA/traffic/sites) only, despite these having a multitude of subdomains each.

While this could be intentional from Gawker, it might also be that Quantcast simply differentiates domains vs. subdomains like so, implying that all the new Stack Exchange sites would only show up as a subdomain of their 'parent site' stackexchange.com (which you aren't quantifying yet), until they get out of beta and a dedicated domain therefore.

Consequently you could start to quantify stackexchange.com as well (which is probably interesting anyway given its increasing exposure), likely all the new Stack Exchange sites are going to show up as subdomains there automatically. Whether this is the correct semantic analysis wise is another question of course.

---

You are likely aware of this, just in case: your sites are at least considered part of the "Stack Overflow Network" already, if looked at individually (type e.g. *stackexchange.com* in the search box and select one):

[image]

This doesn't explain why there are only 3 sites listed still if looked at from the "Stack Overflow Network" perspective indeed, <strike>but it makes your assumption regarding traffic numbers (or a minimum amount of data points over time) somewhat more likely:</strike>

While you expect to be beyond the *30 days worth of data* mentioned in the [Publisher FAQ](http://www.quantcast.com/display-proxy/display/publisher/Using+Quantcast+to+Report+Audience+Data#UsingQuantcasttoReportAudienceData-FAQ5.2) already, their might be some delays or timespan boundaries involved still - given your networks rank I'd be surprised if their support wouldn't answer your respective inquiry ;)